# Python pandas plotting and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I reformulated my question.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   data = [[0, 'cat1', 1, 11], [33, 'cat1', 3, 52], [0, 'cat1', 4, 14], [11, 'cat2', 3, 22], [14, 'cat2', 2, 18], [0, 'cat2', 5, 13]]
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_str, index=['time1', 'time2', 'time2', 'time3', 'time1', 'time1'], columns = ['Text Time',  'Tag', 'Relevance', 'Text length'])
   df = df.sort_index()
   df.plot(x='Text Time', y = 'Relevance')



Text       Time   Tag  Relevance  Text length
time1          0  cat1          1           11
time1         33  cat1          3           52
time2         85  cat1          4           14
time1         11  cat2          3           22
time2         99  cat2          2           18
time3        117  cat2          5           13
```

The `Text Time` column is my time, x axes, and the relevance is the y axes.
Now I would like:

- on the x axes, group the `Text Time` with the index (`time1`, `time2`, `time3`)
- I would like to plot only two lines, `cat1` and `cat2`, each one being represented by the Relevance data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuHTp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you change the question here is the updated answer:

See comments in code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

# read your dataframe and sort
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.drop(columns=['length'], inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'Text.1': 'Text length'}, inplace=True)
df.sort_values(['Text', 'Tag', 'Time'], inplace=True)
x = list(df['Time']) # set x axis by creating a list of time

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # plot mulitple lines
for xlabels, group in df.groupby(['Tag']): # group by Tag
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(str) # change time to a string to create xticks
    xticks = list(df['Time']+'\n'+df['Text']+'\n'+df['Tag']) # create xticks

    group.plot(kind='line',x='Time', y='Relevance', ax=ax)
    ax.legend(['Cat1', 'Cat2'])
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    plt.xticks(x, xticks)

    # resize plot
    pos1 = ax.get_position()
    pos2 = [pos1.x0, pos1.y0,  pos1.width + 1, pos1.height + .5]
    ax.set_position(pos2)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for your answer but  I still don't get a segment per category, don't I?

Comment: @user1889342 updated answer

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks great!

Comment: i'm testing your code but I am not able to actually plot the graph. i've tried plt.show() but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @user1889342 add `%matplotlib inline`